# Trying to exclude certain users

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

New to SQL but I'm trying to find `titles` wherein the words "blue" and "black" are present. However, they cannot be from users who have ids of 1 and 5. This is what I did:

```
SELECT title, id_card
FROM site
WHERE (title LIKE "%blue%" OR title LIKE "%black%")
  AND (id_card != 1 OR id_card != 5)
ORDER BY id_card ASC;
```

However, when I add that id 1 and id 5 shouldn't be in the query, it shows me something like this:

| Blog Title | User |
| --- | --- |
| The blue sky was so nice today | 1 |
| Black is my favorite color | 2 |
| I'm feeling blue | 2 |
| She was dressed in black | 3 |

However, when I erase `id_card != 5` from the code, it works perfectly fine.

| Blog Title | User |
| --- | --- |
| Black is my favorite color | 2 |
| I'm feeling blue | 2 |
| She was dressed in black | 3 |

I'm just wondering where I went wrong and how I can fix this issue. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm confused.  SQL Server would generate a syntax error on your code.  It does not use double quotes for strings.

Comment: FYI I recommend getting into the habit of using whitespace and line breaks early; it'll make even simple statements far easier to read.

Comment: Maybe the OP has `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;` @GordonLinoff . I hope not though...

Comment: @Larnu Or maybe OP has a column called `%blue%` (I really, really hope not.... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=31f1576696491b18d563856def971c4d)

Comment: Your code doesn't search for words, just a short strings. Is it a problem that `'%black%` matches `'Bootblacks shine my shoes'`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on the right track.  But use `not in` to get the logic right:

```
SELECT title, id_card
FROM site
WHERE (title LIKE '%blue%' OR title LIKE '%black%') AND
      id_card NOT IN (1, 5)
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

You could also fix your logic by using `AND`.

Answer (score 1):

Gordon has given you the literal answer but I'm not sure whether it helped you understand the original mistake, so I'm going to add a little more information.

Your original construct was...

```sql
AND (id_card != 1 OR id_card != 5)
```

Imagine the id card of a row was 1. Let's check the first condition

```
id_card != 1
```

Does our row pass this test? No, because the id card does equal 1. So we don't pass this test. The expression `1 != 1` is `false`.

But wait, we have an `or` condition here. So if the `or` condition is satisfied, the whole condition might still be `true`. Let's check it...

```
id_card !=5
```

Does 1 not equal 5? Yes, 1 does not equal 5. So we do pass this test. The expression `1 !=5` is `true`.

So if we look at the expression as a whole, we get:

```
and (false or true)
```

Well, since one side of the `or` condition is `true`, the whole condition is true. That's how `or` works.

Since the condition is true, this part of the `where` clause isn't going to filter it out. So we get back rows where `id_card` = 1.

Notice that the condition `(id_card != 1 or id_card != 5)` will be true *no matter what value the `id_card` has*, because for any value you choose, the value can't be both 1 and 5. Either it's not 1, or it's not 5. So at least one side of the `or` condition is always true.